# jquery: click and pull similar to chrome web store sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, touch, slideshow

I did make a simple slider from scratch

And I want to add click and pull feature With mouse pointer like [Chrome web store Sliders](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/apps)

And touch friendly for any device support touch

Is there any jQuery plugins or tutorials to begin with?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got It after a lot of search

This if you want a ready yo use slider

Swiper by iDangero.us
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

or slideshow jssor
http://slideshow.jssor.com/

And this one if you want just the effect to use it on your projects

TouchSwipe a jQuery plugin for touch devices
http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/